# In PostgreSQL timezone offset is taken with the wrong sign

Tags: database, postgresql, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm experimenting with PostgreSQL `TIME` datatype and I notice a strange behavior.

```
test=# SELECT CURRENT_TIME;
current_time
--------------------
08:43:35.446737+00
(1 row)

test=# SELECT CURRENT_TIME  AT TIME ZONE '+04';
timezone
--------------------
04:43:50.475164-04
(1 row)

test=# SELECT CURRENT_TIME  AT TIME ZONE '-04';
  timezone
--------------------
12:43:54.810124+04
(1 row)
```

As you can notice, the default timezone is **00**, so when I convert it **+04**, I expect to get the result that I get when converting it with **-04**

Is anyone familiar with the reasons behind this behavior or this is a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using POSIX style time zone names, which work a bit strangely.  From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES):

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations west of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.

Also, from the same docs:

> We do not recommend using the type time with time zone (though it is supported by PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance with the SQL standard).